# Sending 2 requests using 1 html page

Tags: html, iframe

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type = "text/javascript">    
    function changeone() {
         parent.document.getElementByID("frame2").src= "www.MyWebsite.com"
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>    
  <iframe id= "frame1" src= "CustomPageCreated.html" width="300" height="500" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" onload = changeone() >  </iframe>
  <iframe id= "frame2"  width="300" height="500" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" >  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

The custom page loads in the frame but the `www.mywebsite.com` does not load in the 2nd frame, Is there anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DOM probably hasn't fully loaded. In addition to the changes @sroes mentioned, try putting the script tag right before the closing `</body>` tag. The following works for me.

```
<iframe id="frame1" style="width:400px;height:400px;" onLoad="loadSite2();"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></iframe>
<script>
var site1 = 'http://rice.edu',
    site2 = 'http://bing.com';
function loadSite2() {
    document.getElementById('frame2').src = site2;
}
document.getElementById('frame1').src = site1;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `parent.` and change `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById("frame2").src= "http://www.MyWebsite.com"
```

**Edit:**

Also make sure you add quotes to the onload attribute:

```
<iframe id= "frame1" src= "CustomPageCreated.html" width="300" height="500" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" onload="changeone()">  </iframe>
```

Comment: have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqKsr/) which did work for me.